# Delete all but newest folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I am having trouble coming up with a method for safely deleting all but the most recently created or updated folder in a provided root directory. I have this basic structure setup, but I am not sure how to proceed from here:

```
for root, folders, files in os.walk(output_folder):
    for folder in folders:
```

Comment: This is question is not a dot a duplicate! The linked question is about removing files older than X days, this question is about removing all folders except the newest (regardless of date!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:-

```
import os
import datetime as dt
import shutil


now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(minutes=30) #Mention the required time

for root, dirs,files in os.walk('/home/piyush/pppptest'): #put required directory path
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)    
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime) #Gives you the modified time of file
        # print mtime
        if mtime > ago:
            print('%s modified %s'%(path, mtime)) #You can check path and modified and work on it as per your requirement
            shutil.rmtree('path') #You can delete it.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the newest folder like this

```
import os, shutil

newest_folder = max(folders, key=os.path.getmtime)

for fname in folders:
    if fname != newest_folder:
        shutil.rmtree(folder)
```

You may want to use `getctime` instead of `getmtime` depending on your exact requirements